# issue in installing ambassador over kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install ambassador over kubernetes.

I am getting the ambassdor pods status as **CrashLoopBackOff**
http://paste.openstack.org/show/658099/

steps followed for installation:

**https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/getting-started**
1) kubectl apply -f ambassador-service.yaml
2) kubectl apply -f https://getambassador.io/yaml/ambassador/ambassador-rbac.yaml

ERROR says:

**Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.241.96.13:8877/ambassador/v0/check_ready: dial tcp 10.241.96.13:8877: getsockopt: connection refused**

please help.

Answer (score 3):

The Ambassador readiness probe is failing, causing Kubernetes to restart the pod, and putting you into a crash loop.

The first thing to do is bump up the `initialDelaySeconds` and `periodSeconds` in your readiness/liveness check (in your deployment YAML) to, say, 60 seconds.

Then, take a look at the Ambassador logs (`kubectl logs <ambassador-pod-name>`) to see if you can see any anomalous issues.

Comment: To see if... ??